# How do I create a list where I can track states and still not create a new one each time? (jetpaсk compose)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I'm making an android app, it's going to be a card game.

```
val players = arrayOf(
    Player(1, "00", 0),
    Player(2, "00", 0),
    Player(3, "00", 0),
    Player(4, "00", 0),
    Player(5, "00", 0),
    Player(6, "00", 0),
    Player(7, "00", 0),
    Player(8, "00", 0),
    Player(9, "00", 0),
    Player(10, "00", 0),
)
val playersState = remember { mutableStateListOf(*players) }
```

Then I call the display functions:

```
showPlayers(stateBottomToggle, playersState)
showHandSelection(stateBottomToggle, playersState, value1, value2, value3)
```

How to create such a list, so that when a change is made in it, the screen is redrawn, without creating the whole list again (as it is resource-intensive).

Ideally, it seems to me, to create a class that will store all common and individual settings, that is, a few switches and this list of players. And pass this instance of the class to each function and work with it. Is it possible to do this and if not, then what can be done?

This is how it works for me at the moment:

```
players[selectedPlayer-1].hand = key_to_hand_h[hand]
playersState.removeRange(0, 10)
playersState.addAll(players)
```

That is, I change the original array and then delete the state array and completely recreate it.
Of course I find this ineffective and would like to know what can be done?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [`set`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/set.html#set) function of [`MutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/) which is the type that is returned by [`mutableStateListOf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#mutableStateListOf()):

> `abstract operator fun set(index: Int, element: E): E` 
> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.

To update a single element in a list, you can use the following code:

```
playersState.set(
    selectedPlayer - 1,                                           // index to update
    playersState[selectedPlayer - 1].copy(hand = key_to_hand_h[hand])  // updated Player
)
```

You can write it even simpler using [operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#indexed-access-operator):

```
playersState[selectedPlayer - 1] = playersState[selectedPlayer - 1].copy(hand = key_to_hand_h[hand])
```

By using the [`copy`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying) function, you create a new `Player` instance with the same values and only update the `hand` value.

Please note that `Player` should be a data class with immutable properties like this:

```
data class Player(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val age: Int
)
```

Comment: `copy` only makes sense if the `Player` objects are immutable. Which they probably aren't, since op's code `players[selectedPlayer-1].hand = key_to_hand_h[hand]` seems to compile for them. It *should* be immutable, though, and *then* `copy` is the correct way to hande updates.

Comment: Also, you take the player object to update from the `players` array and save the updated version in the `playersState` list. This way multiple updates will overwrite all previous changes. You probably want to take the player object to update from the `playersState` list instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and comments. I have tried all of the above methods. Yes indeed, I can change the playersState directly, that's the best. Then maybe the "players" array is not needed at all. 
...
What do you say about creating a class object. It will probably work only if I make the class local, inside MainScreen(), and each variable inside the class should be remember{}. Then I will be able to put playersStates there too. Will it work?

Comment: Thanks @Leviathan for pointing these things out, I edited my answer accordingly. Didn't proofread my own answer enough...

Comment: @AlexanderGromov Your data should be placed in Composables or inside a ViewModel, putting data into a class is not a common practice in Jetpack Compose.

Comment: @BenjyTec Thank you. Here's another question. If I change 1 object from playersState, for example playersState[0], will jetpack compose redraw all components that access playersState, or only one component that works with playersState[0]?

Comment: @AlexanderGromov I am pretty sure it only recomposes the Composables that depend on the actually changed item. You can verify this yourself however by using the Layout Inspector in Android Studio, check out [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/debugging-the-recomposition-in-jetpack-compose-16e92cbc9c6#:~:text=Compose%20starts%20identifying%20the%20scope,%3E%20Tools%20%3E%20Layout%20inspector) for an explanation how to do so.